# odds probability question

Tags: probability

If the probability of winning a game is 0.25,than the odds against winning can be expressed as a:b,in simplest form .The value of a is?

my work:
Since 25/100=0.25 which is the probability of winning a game.and the odds against winning the game For 25 to 100 odds against winning;

Probability of:
Winning = (0.8) or 80%
Losing = (0.2) or 20%

"Odds for" winning: 4:1
"Odds against" winning: 1:4

so the answer:  odds against winning can be expressed as a:b so 1:4,so the value of a is 1
answer=value of a is 1

Comment: Hint: $$p=\frac b{a+b}.$$

Comment: i dont understand @user. IS my answer correct if not whats the correct answer?

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. Solve the above equation to obtain the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of winning is p = 0.25 = 1/4.
So the probability of not winning is 0.75.

Hence, the odds against winning are 0.75 / 0.25 = 3:1.

So $a = 3$